# Header too long error while decoding C# RSACryptoServiceProvider-derived Public Key with OpenSSL

Tags: c#, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I generated an RSA Public Key in C# with RSACryptoServiceProvider with a key size of 512-bits.

```
// Generate a public/private key using RSA
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);

// Read public key in a string  
string str = RSA.ToXmlString(true);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

```
// XML output
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>26+2lMVkqh99O3nBV/EU5KkO3FYx7R/0Fnlh6FES2wvIAZ6yaHrAhrX6a/BWag4N/XRH3z+nxQBRiG1pPUDQKQ==</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
<P>9y6RKpt6OsQFoPfsxo9+NpSJF2xrWg9+h+f6ri7svv8=</P>
<Q>44YJ0p9qDJuvIM+PaFi9p8NpYerSUAfO49camwH7mNc=</Q>
<DP>Zw9ebXJn8yqZ4jSc32kiyaUCx+ZnmCRPsGCzr35XLYc=</DP>
<DQ>Gn4OAL9dKtCp6KkiaqUCmFkxmRwtlvIBzhfK2ke10ws=</DQ>
<InverseQ>6bwnrFXgBggw2+9fyaPP4femrMH3VQgxBkj8P1B3TTs=</InverseQ>
<D>SJpisfomkZ7EiZJsln7DU+qXUbRe3aowxfippdidbaxzM3+lMgLH2V8q9Ba7M8leG8mxkvttdilojclFFi9q3Q==</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I throw the Modulus value into a PEM file:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
26+2lMVkqh99O3nBV/EU5KkO3FYx7R/0Fnlh6FES2wvIAZ6yaHrAhrX6a/BWag4N/XRH3z+nxQBRiG1pPUDQKQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

OpenSSL is not able to decode the Public Key, however. Here is the command I used:

```
openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -text -noout < public-key.pem
```

And here is the result with errors:

```
unable to load Public Key
30844:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:crypto\asn1\asn1_lib.c:101:
30844:error:0D068066:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:bad object header:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1137:
30844:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error:crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:309:Type=X509_PUBKEY
30844:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:crypto\pem\pem_oth.c:33:
```

Why can't OpenSSL decode this Public Key? I even tried the default key size of 1024-bits and it still couldn't read it. Is there a compatibility issue between OpenSSL and the RSACryptoServiceProvider class? How can I get OpenSSL to properly read and decode this Public Key?

Comment: A PEM is not only header, footer and Base64 encoded modulus, but contains more data. Typical formats for a public key are X.509/SPKI or PKCS#1 stored in ASN.1 which can be PEM or DER encoded. There are online converters for xml to PEM encoding, e.g. https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter. If you need only the public key, remove P, Q, DP, DQ, InverseQ and D in the xml before converting with the online converter.

Comment: Note that in NET Core 3.0 and later, DER encoded keys can be exported _directly_, e.g. [`ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.exportsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=netcore-3.0). These can be quickly PEM encoded by Base64 encoding and adding the appropriate header/footer. In other versions or .NET Framework BouncyCastle can be used.

Comment: @user901407 Thank you. That helped. I see that I have to combine the two components, modulus and exponent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt?view=net-5.0) to create the Public Key. I got it to work such that OpenSSL can properly decode it now. Thanks again.